# Why is the array key missing the last ] when passing field data via AJAX to PHP function?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Im using this code to get an object of field input names and values to pass to an AJAX function.

```
var fields = {};
$("#wrap").find(":input").each(function() {
    fields[this.name] = $(this).val();
});

var obj = {fields: fields};
```

The AJAX call to a PHP function

```
var data = {
    'action': 'my_function',
    'fields': obj,
};

jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {

    console.log(response);

});
```

The fields are:

```
<div id="wrap">
<input type="number" min="0" name="my_array[123][somelabel]" value="">
<input type="number" min="0" name="my_array[456][somelabel]" value="">
</div>
```

The PHP just does:

```
print_r( $_POST['fields'] );
```

**Result & My Expected Result**

In the response console log this returns an array with the first key of fields as `my_array[123`

I am expecting this to be `my_array[123]` - why is it missing the last `]` ?

Comment: try to return json_encode of $_POST['fields']

Comment: In that the array key is still missing the last `]`

Comment: it seems the problem is in js and not in php

Comment: If `console.log` is showing you an array looks like jQuery is trying to convert the response. Try specifying `dataType: 'text'` in your request.

Comment: @msg still the same

Comment: before sending it, try to console.log obj variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your array assignment code like below:-

```
var fields = []; //empty array
$("#wrap").find(":input").each(function() {
    var obj = {
      $(this).attr('name'): $(this).val()
   }; //created object with key value pair
  fields.push(obj); //add object to array
});
```